# Domain and codomain of a generalization of the gradient

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Assuming we have a differentiable function
$$ f: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R} $$
where $ \mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}$. What are the domain and codomain of $\nabla f$?

This type of functions appear when the definition of the [Reproducing kernel Hilbert space is extended to vector-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Extension_to_vector-valued_functions).

An example would be a function where the integer elements of the input pairs are used to extract entries of a matrix. More specifically, if $A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, we can define such a function as
$$
f((x,i),(y,j)) = g(x,y)A_{ij}
$$

Comment: That implies that you can have a meaningful definition of differentiability on the natural numbers first, doesn't it?

Comment: Could it be that the derivatives are only taken with respect to the real coordinates? 
For example, in your link, your function is defined, but never differentiated in discrete directions.  
Do you have a concrete problem when you need the gradient of $f$? Or is it just curiosity?  :)   (PS: Are you looking for a discrete gradient? Like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference )

Comment: @SteffenPlunder It is curiosity and a bit of confusion that I'm getting after dealing with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation systems and indeed finite differences.

Comment: After thinking a bit about it, I feel more and more that you probably can define the derivative of $f$ for whatever structure you prefer, but it will be less useful than the continious counterparts. 
You want it to be a linear map between tangent spaces, sure, that works. But you won't get nice proberties like $\partial_x \partial_i f = \partial_i \partial_x f$. 
Knowing what you actually want to do could help.
PS: AD might just be able to compute the derivative of $A_{i,j}$, but that is because your code defines $A_{i,j}$ in a way which might also make sense for $i, j \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: I want to know what does $f'$ or $\nabla f$ output, so to speak. A point in $\mathbb{R}^2$? (if it even makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered so far. Here are my thoughts. **I am not an expert on this!**

Maybe this is interesting for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_calculus#Calculus_of_differences_and_sums

---

My thoughts below are more about what doesn't work:

There is no single choice for a discrete differential.
For specific applications, you have different preferences.

Usually, the derivative of a function evaluated at a point $x$ is the best linear approximation of $f$ around $x$.
If $f$ was given over manifolds, $f : \mathcal M \to \mathcal N$, then the derivative at $x \in \mathcal M$ is a linear map between the tangent spaces
$$
Df(x) : T_x \mathcal M \to T_{f(x)} \mathcal N.
$$
(Think of the tangent spaces are the linear approximation of the nonlinear manifolds around that point.)

If $f$ is a map between linear spaces, $f : X \to Y$, then you don't need to use the tangent spaces since the domain and target are already linear, hence, the derivative is a linear map
$$
Df(x) : X \to Y.
$$
The defining property is
$$
\quad \Vert f(x+v) - (f(x) + Df(x) v) \Vert \to 0 \quad \text{(for }\Vert v \Vert \to 0\text{)} \quad\quad (1).
$$

**How does this fail for $\mathbb{N}$?**

- $\mathbb{N}$ is not a linear space. There is no clear notion of what a linear approximation could be.
- The is no way to ask for the same defining property like above in Eq. $(1)$. Functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ can behave very arbitrary. Hence, you only have the choice to pick that one vector $v$ in Eq. $(1)$ and require that at least this holds. For example, we can pick $v = 1$ and then require that
  $$
  f(x) + \Delta_+ f(x+1) \cdot 1 = f(x+1) 
  $$

**How about $\mathbb{N}^2$?**

I actually don't know!
Probably you have a lot of bad choices to pick from.

Let's pick:
$$
\Delta_+ f(x,y) = ( f(x+1,y) - f(x,y), \, f(x,y+1) - f(x,y) ) \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 2}
$$
(Yes, there are many options how we could interpret this. Is it a linear map? Did we obtain it by extending $f$ to a map $\overline{f} : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$?  Maybe. Anyway, I just consider it as a row vector without getting into this mess.)

This corresponds to requiring equation $(1)$ for $v = (1,0)^T$ and $v = (0,1)^T$. Hence, ​we get:
$$
f(x+1,y) = f(x,y) + \Delta_+ f(x,y) \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
f(x,y+1) = f(x,y) + \Delta_+ f(x,y) \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Some nice properties follow from that. But most properties of normal derivatives do not hold!

For example, there is no hope for symmetry of second derivatives.

**What can a discrete derivative do?**

There are calculus rules for discrete derivatives, which are usually not too hard to prove.

To give one example:

The continuous rule $$\int_a^b f'(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = f(a) - f(b)$$
​becomes for $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\sum_{i=a}^{b-1} \Delta_{+} f(i) = f(a) - f(b).
$$
Asking for properties related to sums is easier and a weaker requirement in some sense.

This gives rise to a more abstract definition of what a forward difference is:
Quote Wikipedia: It is a $1$-chain. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_(algebraic_topology))

You can think of a $1$-chain as an object which has a starting point and an endpoint (e.g. $x$ and $x+1$) and you can assign a value to it which basically says how much a quantity of interest changes along that $1$-chain. So, it exactly carries the information the finite-difference has. You can append chains together, i.e.
$\Delta_+ f(x+1) '+' \Delta_+f(x)$ is a $1$-chain from $x$ to $x+2$ which tells you how much $f$ changes from $x$ to $x+2$.

These $1$-chain's are objects from algebraic topology/differential geometry which are related to exterior derivatives. One motivation of this theory is to generalise the Stokes theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem).

If these things are interesting for you, you can read up a bit on discrete exterior calculus, etc. But it's for sure not the most practical way if you just want to prove simple properties for you discrete gradient.